# How would I extract username, post, and date posted from discussion board?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, data-mining

How would I proceed in this web scraping project using bs4 and requests? I am trying to extract user info from a forum site (myfitnesspal exactly: https://community.myfitnesspal.com/en/discussion/10703170/what-were-eating/p1), specifically the username, message, and date posted, and load them into columns on a csv. I have this code so far but am unsure about how to proceed:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests

# get page source and create a BS object
print('Reading page...')

page= requests.get('https://community.myfitnesspal.com/en/discussion/10703170/what-were-eating/p1')
src = page.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

#container = soup.select('#vanilla_discussion_index > div.container')

container = soup.select('#vanilla_discussion_index > div.container > div.row > div.content.column > div.CommentsWrap > div.DataBox.DataBox-Comments > ul')

postdata = soup.select('div.Message')

user = []
date = []
text = []

for post in postdata:
    text.append(BeautifulSoup(str(post), 'html.parser').get_text().encode('utf-8').strip())

print(text) # this stores the text of each comment/post in a list,
            # so next I'd want to store this in a csv with columns 
            # user, date posted, post with this under the post column
            # and do the same for user and date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will get all messages from the page and saves them in `data.csv`:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://community.myfitnesspal.com/en/discussion/10703170/what-were-eating/p1'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for u, d, m in zip(soup.select('.Username'), soup.select('.DateCreated'), soup.select('.Message')):
    all_data.append([u.text, d.get_text(strip=True),m.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')])

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Screenshot from LibreOffice:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this one worked! If you don't mind, I have some questions about your code: 1. what does get_text() do and why the Strip parameter? 2. what does newline in open() and delimiter in write() do? I am new to scraping and saving data so I'd like to know for future reference.

Comment: @MarcelinoVelasquez get_text just gets string from the tag. [.get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) has two parameters: `strip=True|False` that has same function than `str.strip()` - it just strip whitespace characters around string, and `separator=<some string>` that separates tags with this character. For the second question: [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open-newline-parameter) has an answer. I used the example from official `csv` module documentation.

Answer (score 2):

One rule of thumb I like to follow with web scraping is being *specific as possible* without picking up unnecessary information. So for example, if I want to select a username I inspect the element containing the information I need:

```
<a class="Username" href="...">Username</a>
```

Since I am trying to collect usernames it makes the most sense to select by the class "Username":

```
soup.select("a.Username")
```

This gives me a list of all the usernames that are found on the page, this is great, however, if we want to select the data in "packages" (by post in your example we need to collect each post individually.

To accomplish this you could do something like the following:

```
comments = soup.select("div.comment")
```

This will make it easier to then do the following:

```
with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['user', 'date', 'text']
    for comment in comments:
        username = comment.select_one("div.Username")
        date = comment.select_one("span.BodyDate")
        message = comment.select_one("div.Message")
        writer.writerow([username, date, message])
```

Doing it this way also makes sure your data stays in order even if an element is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your implementation and the header was written but the data wasn't. I am not an expert, but maybe it is because the answer I check marked had the data already stored in a list before beginning to write into a csv. I would think this shouldn't matter however which is why I am probably wrong lol

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests


page= requests.get('https://community.myfitnesspal.com/en/discussion/10703170/what-were-eating/p1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
container = soup.select('#vanilla_discussion_index > div.container > div.row > div.content.column > div.CommentsWrap > div.DataBox.DataBox-Comments > ul > li')

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['user', 'date', 'text'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for comment in container:
        writer.writerow({
            'user': comment.find('a', {'class': 'Username'}).get_text(),
            'date': comment.find('span', {'class': 'BodyDate DateCreated'}).get_text().strip(),
            'text': comment.find('div', {'class': 'Message'}).get_text().strip()
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this implementation and it only got me the first row. Maybe I integrated with my code the wrong way but I thought I'd let you know. Like I commented to Aero, it may be because the data wasn't already stored in a list before writing to csv, but I would think this doesn't matter so I am probably wrong.

Comment: @MarcelinoVelasquez Only one way to find out. Run it as a standalone script and you'll see all the data appear inside `data.csv`.